# Cannot use a member typedef of one class as a template parameter in a template specialization definition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

Sorry for the long and ambiguous title.

I have been trying to practice what I have learned from the book "Modern C++ Design". As part of this activity, I am both trying to implement the Command Pattern as described in the book, and trying to migrate it to C++11.

I am in this state right now: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42a80b7b749ef74d)

I implemented `TypeListGenerator<...>` to replace `TYPELIST_N(...)` to be able to make use of variadic templates:

```
// without variadic templates
#define TYPELIST_0() NullType
#define TYPELIST_1(T1) TypeList<T1, NullType>
#define TYPELIST_2(T1, T2) TypeList<T1, TYPELIST_1(T2)>
...

// with variadic templates
template <typename Head, typename... Rest> struct TypeListGenerator {
    using result = TypeList<Head, typename TypeListGenerator<Rest...>::result>;
};
template <> struct TypeListGenerator<NullType> {
    using result = NullType;
};
template <typename Last> struct TypeListGenerator<Last> {
    using result = TypeList<Last, NullType>;
};
```

Now the problem in the following code:

```
template <typename R, typename P1>
//class FunctorImpl<R, typename TypeListGenerator<P1>::result> { // <-- #1 - Does not compile
class FunctorImpl<R, TYPELIST_1(P1)> { //<-- #2 - Compiles
    public:
    virtual R operator()(P1) = 0;
    virtual FunctorImpl* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~FunctorImpl() = 0;
};

template <typename R, typename TL>
class Functor {
    using P1 = typename TypeAtNonStrict<TL, 0, EmptyType>::type;
    using P2 = typename TypeAtNonStrict<TL, 1, EmptyType>::type;
    using P3 = typename TypeAtNonStrict<TL, 2, EmptyType>::type;
    using P4 = typename TypeAtNonStrict<TL, 3, EmptyType>::type;
public:
    Functor() : impl_(nullptr) { }
    R operator()() { return (*impl_)(); }
    R operator()(P1 p1) { return (*impl_)(p1); }
    R operator()(P1 p1, P2 p2) { return (*impl_)(p1, p2); }
    R operator()(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3) { return (*impl_)(p1, p2, p3); }
private:
    FunctorImpl<R, TL>* impl_;
};

int main() {
    Functor<double, typename TypeListGenerator<int>::result> f1;
    double r1 = f1(1);
}
```

is that if I uncomment #1, it compiles. But if I uncomment #2, it does not and gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:148:7: error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
 class FunctorImpl<R, typename TypeListGenerator<P1>::result> {
       ^
main.cpp:148:7: error:         'P1'
```

Note: I just show the important parts of the code, the full code is at [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42a80b7b749ef74d)

Comment: Note that you may use `std::tuple` `std::tuple_element` and `std::get` instead of `TypeList`.

Comment: `impl_` is always `nullptr`, so the crash.

Comment: Yes, I am intentionally not using std::tuple, once I am done with the way it is handled in the book, I will migrate it to std::tuple

Comment: I know it crashes. My problem is it does not compile if I use TypeListGenerator instead of TYPELIST_N. Once I pass this error, I will handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of non-deduced context. An informal explanation of non-deduced context is given below, much more info can be found with a google search.

In simple words, given `X` and `X<Y>::Z`, you cannot deduce `Y`.

Suppose `TypeListGenerator<Foo>::result` is `int`, and `TypeListGenerator<Bar>::result` is also `int`.

You pass `int` to your template, does it have a chance to ever understand it's actually `TypeListGenerator<Foo>::result` and not `TypeListGenerator<Bar>::result`? Nope.

But I carefully define my `TypeListGenerator<Foo>::result` in a unique way such that it's actually possible to recover `P1`, you say. Doesn't matter. The procedure to recover it does not exist in the general case, so the language rules say it is not done.